# Need a type magic to type the return of a function that replace objects keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The problem here is that the type from the object that will return needs to have all the keys from O, which is our initial input, without the keys contained in R. In addition it shoudld have the values from R that will replace the omitted keys from O.

So, here's is the function so far:

```
type JSObject = {
  [key: string | number | symbol]: unknown
}

export function replace<O extends JSObject, R extends { [K in keyof O]?: string }>(
  object: O,
  replacement: R
): Omit<O, keyof R> {
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${Object.keys(replacement).join('|')})`, 'g')
  const stringify = JSON.stringify(object).replace(regex, (match) => replacement[match] ?? match)
  return JSON.parse(stringify)
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just renaming keys? In that case I would [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76000053/edit) the post and make that more clear. Also, this implementation easily breaks. What if a key contains regex metacharacters?

Comment: Please provide example usage

Comment: Maybe you want something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8XQ0w)?

Comment: You should be very clear what the point of the function is with example inputs and outputs and then probably remove that implementation because it's.... [not good](https://tsplay.dev/NllXON).

Comment: Sorry, about not being clear.
it's a fcuntion to replace keys from json objects easily.

For example if your input is `replace({ id: 1, foo: 2, baz: 3 }, { foo: 'bar' })` it should return `{ id: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }`.

For some reason the @pink solution isn't working here, maybe it's a TS version I'm gonna check.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand yes, TS does have type key mapping

```
type A = { id: 1, foo: 2, baz: 3 }
type B = { foo: 'bar' }

type Replace<O, R extends Record<any, PropertyKey>> = {
    [K in keyof O
        as K extends keyof R ? R[K] : K
    ]: O[K]
}

type C = Replace<A, B>
//   ^?
// type C = { id: 1; bar: 2; baz: 3; }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCWATAXFAjAGigDMB7Y7AJgICMBDAL2wGYoBfAWAChRIoAhBZEVLYA5LQBOI1p07doAJQhgANjQDGEADwB5AvKgQAHsAgA7dAGcoitcXHpNNUyAIAFccUjjQAaQggAPgCBJE4ocKgAbR80UygAa39iQihtMIiMmisYoxNzK0SQZOsoAH5raIBdKGwfdPDK7G0qznYOWXBoAGEBRRV1LRgCXgDOAHoxiIA9UvHJuSgexBQMbBwAbigJCk3aBihGTbagA)

---

edit: here's a proper implementation, [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCWATAXFAjAGigDMB7Y7AJgICMBDAL2wGYoBfAWAChRIoAhBZEVLYA5LQBOI1p07doAJQhgANjQDGEADwB5AvKgQAHsAgA7dAGcoitcXHpNNUyAIAFccUjjQAaQggAPgCBJE4ocKgAbR80UygAa39iQihtMIiMmisYoxNzK0SQZOsoAH5raIBdKGwfdPDK7G0qznYOWXBoAGEBRRV1LRgCXgDOAHoxiIA9UvHJuSgexBQMbBwAbigJCk3aBihGTbbOQgBXUzVgVGI48TMaAFsIPxALHQNjM0tBSItsC2A4lQpgA5o0oOd4qZiAB3UxHPQfPLfFC-f6A4Fg7DuTwQbwgF5HAIACnqUGIVAAVhBLk08GS7v0NE9TMBsPJOABKdlKVQaHR6YKhDgZO7AU7iOLaKk04AAOkIHgeAFFWUCIBZSSKMhFpdTLnKzBiNcSKfrgJyyTqInKHjQwMTiZFCgQAG40ZSnCCVTkIYKRVIyg0ACyy2jhxMZfIgLOABEKvvKUYGsed-mq2BdUHdnu9lu14V9WWsvIGAusow4xw4tlMFmIyggcuUxBBkfuTxempWWFwBBIZCglC29CYrAIKAHogkUhYnPzE2QcwiACIMCu1vSOIvwiuJBuh1ud1A9-QD4xlywoEA) (note: it doesn't JSONClones values)

```
function renameKeys<O extends { [s: string]: unknown; }, R extends { [s: string]: PropertyKey; }>(
    object: O,
    replacement: R
): Replace<O, R> {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(object)
            .map(([key, value]) => [ Object.hasOwn(replacement, key) ? replacement[key] : key, value])
    ) as Replace<O, R>
}
```